# Is there a way to find all Overlays attached to a map?

Tags: google-maps

I have a gmap object that is created by a JSF components (PrimeFaces p:gmap) and it might have some Overlays (Markers) attached to it.   So my own client-side javascript doesn't have a direct reference the Overlay objects.

Is there some way where I can get a collection of all the Overlays currently painted on a map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with v3 of the Maps API, no. There is no documented method to do this.

A internal array somewhere *might* hold it, but you couldn't rely on it ( and its obfuscated short name would change with each release).

Comment: That explains why I couldn't find it.  It does seem like a curious omission from the API, however.  At some point the logic in the core object needs to know this (or it wouldn't be able to plot the map with all its Overlays) so it has to maintain a data structure.  I wonder what the reason for not exposing it is?

Comment: I'm guessing it helps avoid memory leaks and avoids the maintainance overhead. In therory most applications are going to need to keep a record of markers etc. So why bother maintaining a proper list. Interally the overlays are probably held in seperate lists, or even just as dom objects etc. Making a central list an overhead.